# Why does current_user session become nil when updating a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I'm using Devise and CanCan for user authentication and administrating roles restricting access to parts of my Rails 4 app for certain users.

I've run into some problems with updating a user. The update works fine and the user object in the db get updated as it should, but my user session is lost on the following `redirect_to` my user show action. `current_user` becomes `nil` which means that CanCan restricts the access to the user show action.

Why does `current_user` become `nil` after update, when this does not happen on other actions (e.g create, destroy etc.)?

These are the devise settings in my user model:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]
```

This is my users_controller.rb's update method:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if params[:user][:password].blank?
        params[:user].delete(:password)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to user_path, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my ability.rb file:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if defined?(user.role_id)
      if user.role? :admin, user.role_id
        can :manage, :all
      elsif user.role? :hauler, user.role_id
        can :manage, [User,Trip,Invoice], user_id: user.id.to_s
      else
        can :create, :Trip
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the update being performed.  Sessions are serialized with certain bits of user data.

For instance updating the password will cause a  session to be nullified because the encrypted password is part of the serialized hash, and if that is changed, the session can no longer reference the original encrypted password.

Comment: Thanks trh. The redirect works fine if i update the user without updating the password. So according to what you're saying, I need to log the user back in if he/she changes the password, correct?

Comment: yes - specifically `sign_in @user, :bypass => true` -- you can see more info here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me

```
def update

    respond_to do |format|

      if @user.update(user_params)

        sign_in(@user, :bypass=>true)

        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }

      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end

    end

end
```

Magic happens in  :bypass=>true